# Oracle Report generating in Greek language

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oraclereports, nls-lang

After the migration Oracle application from Windows(on premise) to Unix(cloud), reports are generated in Greek language. Please help us to generate it in English or French.

Application Server : WebLogic
Oracle version : 12.1.0.2.0

We have made changes in ‘uifont.ali’ file located in ‘/apps/oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/forms_domain/config/fmwconfig/components/ReportsToolsComponent/parisReportsTools/guicommon/tk/admin/’ to configure PDF Subset with fonts details and the corresponding ‘.ttf’ files are placed in ‘/apps/oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/forms_domain/reports/fonts/’

We have set ‘NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8’ in /apps/oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/forms_domain/reports/bin/reports.sh and /apps/oracle/Middleware/bin/reports.sh

Comment: hi, can you provide output of below cmd from bash shell ?
echo $LANG

Comment: output of $LANG is en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're on the right track. I've seen this too and always solved it via NLS_LANG, although in my case there's always been a startup script that I would use, and in that, I'd set NLS_LANG to match the character set of the database.

```
   export NLS_LANG=American_America.WE8ISO8859P1
```

Comment: Thanks. We have tried with English(AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1) and French(FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8MSWIN1252). Since both doesn't worked, we went with unicode set(AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a guess, do you have another %NLS_LANG variables in the system?

Like DEVELOPER_NLS_LANG and USER_NLS_LANG as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_nls002.htm#CBJBEECI)

EDIT: and check the NLS settings on the client side where you are running report from as well